# bulk parking domain using apache and php

Tags: php, apache, dns

how can I park several domain and then detect which domain is called from php?
just like parking domain services. I want to write similar script.

edit:
I am not sure why someone vote to close my question here :|

Comment: This is more of a serverfault question.

Comment: What is the goal? Redirection? Referrer?

Comment: the goal is a parking service maybe show content based of domain so should detect which domain called also.

Answer (score 3):

To get the domain you're currently visiting with php, you can use `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`.

Your question about bulk registration depends on your domain registrar and whether they do provide an API. If they do, documentation and help should be available from them.

Comment: thank you for php tip. about domain, I do not want bulk register it. clients park their domains and not register.